# Change navigation bar tittle text to custom color?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

I am trying to change the title bar text to a custom shade of lavender with the following code in my appDelegate

```swift
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor(red: 0.9069682956, green: 0.7839415669, blue: 0.9612388015, alpha: 1)]

    return true
}
```

However the title bar text is showing up black still. Is there a better way to change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably it is too early, try to add in `init` of `ContentView` and, as well, add some for large title (which is default for SwiftUI NavigationView), like

```
struct ContentView: View {

    init() {
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = 
            [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: 
               UIColor(red: 0.9069682956, green: 0.7839415669, blue: 0.9612388015, alpha: 1)]
        UINavigationBar.appearance().largeTitleTextAttributes = 
            [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: 
               UIColor(red: 0.9069682956, green: 0.7839415669, blue: 0.9612388015, alpha: 1)]
    }

    // ... other code with NavigationView here
}
```

Tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1